# Angular CanActivate Guard like CanDeactivate

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, angular2-routing

I wondering why is the `CanActivate` guard different from `CanDeactivate` guard.

**CanActivate**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class CanActivateGuard implements CanActivate {
  public canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
    return true;
  }
}
```

In this guard you just can check the route and use some of your services.
Great, but wait ... check out the `CanDeactivate` guard.

**CanDeactivate**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanDeactivate } from '@angular/router';

export interface CanComponentDeactivate {
  canDeactivate: () => Promise<boolean> | boolean;
}

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class CanDeactivateGuard implements CanDeactivate<CanComponentDeactivate> {
  public canDeactivate(component: CanComponentDeactivate): Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    return component.canDeactivate ? component.canDeactivate() : true;
  }
}
```

In this guard you have to set a component. It's annoying but in my case I really want it. I come from Ionic 3 and need these guard because Ionic 4 does not have `ionViewCanEnter` and `ionViewCanLeave`. Therefore I created this guard, so you can simple add the method `canDeactive()` to every component / page you have. Simple as `ionViewCanLeave`. Really awesome. BUT I also want it for the `CanActivate`.

Is there a way to use `CanActivate` in the same way as `CanDeactivate`? For the activate guard, I also want to simple use `canActivate()` methods in my components / pages. Like:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';

export interface CanComponentActivate {
  canActivate: () => Promise<boolean> | boolean;
}

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class CanActivateGuard implements CanActivate<CanComponentActivate> {
  public canActivate(component: CanComponentActivate): Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    return component.canActivate ? component.canActivate() : true;
  }
}
```

Just exactly like the deactivate guard. But this does not work.

Heres my **app-routing.module.ts** (Snippet)

```
 { path: 'test', canActivate: [CanActivateGuard], canDeactivate: [CanDeactivateGuard], component: TestPage}
```

**TestPage**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-test-page',
  templateUrl: 'test.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['test.page.scss']
})
export class TestPage {
  public canActivate(): boolean {
    console.log('Sure, come in.');
    return true;
  }

  public canDeactivate(): boolean {
    console.log('Muahahah, never. :P');
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: are different because in guard CanActivate you don't has the component. -it is checked before the componene is loaded-. So you normally **inject a service  in the constructor** -and you can has the ActivatedRouteSnapshot and RouterStateSnapshot  as argument of the function CanActivate-. In canDeactivate you has the component, and you has access to all the properties of the component, so you can make a check over a form, or a variable...

Comment: Sounds plausible. Thanks. Maybe there is a way. I get the Component from the `ActivatedRouteSnapshot`. But not the instance, as you said: The CanActivate guard does not know the instance, until it is not loaded. Okay. I have to create a CanActivate guard for each page who need it. And resolve the boolean over services. No access to the component instance. ... I could use static method of component. But then I have problem to use services. :thinking: ...